# how to show english number keyboard in arabic regions flutter + dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In my application, it support English and arabis language.I want when my app open in arabis region than when input keyboard is for only number then the keyboard type will be English keyboard instead if arabis keyboard. I searched but not get any solution.Please help.

Comment: Do you get solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It only accesses to the current keyboard type the user enabled for usage.
You can only convert from text keyboard to number keyboard using the following code

```
    TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your number"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
],),
```

> There is no functionality available to switch between different
>   keyboards.

You can use custom keyboard via using this package: **[keyboard_actions 3.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions)**

Comment: it's not working , after implementing this arabis keyboard remain same.

Comment: because it will switch from the selected keyboard means from TEXT to NUMBER and vice versa, it will not switch between two different keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

- first add this library (persian_number_utility: ^1.1.0) then use it
  as bellow:

  TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  inputFormatters:[_DigitPersianFormatter(),],
  ),

  ```
  class _DigitPersianFormatter extends TextInputFormatter{   @override 
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue,
  TextEditingValue newValue) {
      String persianInput = newValue.text.toPersianDigit();
      int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
      return newValue.copyWith(
        text: persianInput.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
      );   }   }
  ```